# Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I am using trial version from scheduler. I've tried to insert custom view after this instructions https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view

and I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at i._renderSkeleton (main.min.js:6)
    at i.res [as renderSkeleton] (main.js:3189)
    at i.render (main.min.js:6)
    at i.Component.receiveProps (main.js:3887)
    at CalendarComponent.renderView (main.js:6277)
    at CalendarComponent.render (main.js:6202)
    at CalendarComponent.Component.receiveProps (main.js:3887)
    at Calendar.renderComponent (main.js:6817)
    at Calendar.executeRender (main.js:6774)
    at Calendar.tryRerender (main.js:6755)
    at Calendar.requestRerender (main.js:6747)
    at Calendar.dispatch (main.js:6735)
    at Calendar.changeView (main.js:7006)
    at HTMLButtonElement.buttonClick (main.js:6063)
```

This is part of my code:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
                plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'resourceTimeline'],
                defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
                defaultDate: currentDate,
                editable: true,
                themeSystem: 'standard',
                locale: 'de',
                selectable: true,
                droppable: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today createEvent',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'fourdays,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
                },
                views: {
                    fourdays: {
                        type: 'resourceTimeline',
                        duration: { days: 4 },
                        buttonText: '4Days'
                    }
                }
```

It occurred only when I change to timeline view. Month, Day, Week and List views are working. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can't reproduce your error using 4.4.0 and your code. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/WNNeLNV . There are no console errors, even when changing between views. Perhaps you didn't provide all the needed code / data to reproduce the problem. Can you fork my codepen and make it so the error occurs? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for guidance on creating useful examples / demos. Then we can understand if the bug is in your code or in fullCalendar.

Answer (score 0):

I've downgraded to v4.3.1 and the error doesn't appear anymore. It is obviously a bug.

Comment: This isn't really a solution so much as a workaround.

Comment: I didn't say it is a solution, it's just an info about what I've tried

Comment: If you're posting it as an "Answer", it's a good idea if it actually answers the question by solving the problem, rather than just showing a way to ignore the issue. Especially since , per my comment on the thread above, there's no hard evidence yet that the bug is in fullCalendar (and that therefore downgrading while you wait for a fix to be issued would be a useful solution.)